# Unable to set breakpoint to script even though the javascript is present in the resource tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to set a breakpoint to line 111 in the script 'bootstrap-tokenfield.js' for debugging purpose as seen in the attached picture.

[image]

You can see the javascript is present in the resources.

Why chrome does not let me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put break point by viewing source from "Sources" tab of Developer tools in the chrome.

Answer (score 0):

1. keep the `debugger` on the function where you want to debug
2. Now open the Chrome and Open "Source" tab
3. Now try to reload the page and page will be appear in the Debug Mode
   at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on line number to add breakpoint
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `debugger` statement invokes any available debugging functionality, such as setting a breakpoint. If no debugging functionality is available, this statement has no effect.

**Syntax**

```
debugger;
```

The following example shows code where a debugger statement has been inserted, to invoke a debugger (if one exists) when the function is called.

```
function potentiallyBuggyCode() {
    debugger;
    // do potentially buggy stuff to examine, step through, etc.
}
```

When the debugger is invoked, execution is paused at the debugger statement. It is like a breakpoint in the script source.

[image]

**Reference**

- [https://developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)